# inline-block independent margin in <li>

Tags: html, css, margin

I have the following menu:

```css
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}
li.current {
  background-color: #3eb5f1;
  color: white;
}
li.current::after {
  content: "";
  height: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("../images/nav-arrow.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">Home page</li>
    <li>Inventory</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As shown, the `li.current` element has an icon but I want to add a margin. However, when I define `margin` in `li.current::after`, it affects the whole element; the text inside `<li class="current">` not just the icon.

How can I set the margin of just `li.current::after`? Image - http://oi59.tinypic.com/108658l.jpg

Comment: the problem is because of `text-align: center;`. It affects all the inline contents

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the image? It might help clarify the desired output; you may not need to add a margin.

Comment: Ok, here is image - http://oi59.tinypic.com/108658l.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `display: inline-block`, set the pseudo element's position as absolute.  You can then apply a left margin to it without affecting the text placement of "Home page":

```css
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}
li.current {
  background-color: #3eb5f1;
  color: white;
}
li.current::after {
  content: "image";
  height: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">Home page</li>
    <li>Inventory</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But when text would be another size, i'll need to set another margins for each text size

Comment: Do you want the icon to be placed in the same horizontal position, regardless of the width of the `li` text?  In that case, use absolute position with `left` instead of `margin-left`.

Comment: it is already placed well if we using inline block, but i need to add some space between text and arrow and also margin-top.

See img - http://oi59.tinypic.com/108658l.jpg

Comment: If you want the menu items to be lined up on top of each other, remove `text-align: center`, and apply a left margin to them instead.  You can then position the icons with absolute position and `left` or `margin-left` ... depending on where they should be placed.

Comment: Ok, but if i need to use text-align: center , is there any way to use margin-top independently to the pseudo element without absolute positioning?

Comment: I can't think of another way to do so.  But using `margin-top` instead of `top` with absolute positioning causes it to be moved relative to its normal position.

Comment: Very strange.. Thank you anyway